# How to pass model to a partial when in a loop

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

The model of my page looks like:

```
public class SomeViewModel()
{
    public List<Some> Something1 {get;set;}
    public MySettings Settings {get;set;}

}
```

Now in my view:

```
@foreach(var some in Something1)
{
  @Html.Partial("_Some", some);
}
```

What if I wanted to pass in `Settings` also into the partial, how could I do this?

Comment: Easiest thing would to create another type that contains the `Settings` and a single `Some` and send an instance as a model.

Comment: Good idea, so just set Some in the loop and pass it. thanks.

Comment: If you don't want to bother with another type, you can use a [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create another viewmodel type:

```
public class OtherViewModel()
{
    public OtherViewModel(Some some, MySettings mySettings)
    {
        Some = some;
        MySettings = mySettings;
    }

    public Some Some { get; set; }
    public MySettings Settings { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can use it your view:

```
@foreach(var some in Something1)
{
  @Html.Partial("_Some", new OtherViewModel(some, Model.MySettings));
}
```

You can also use [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class without creating a type but I think the first one is the better approach. Here's how you can do it anyway:

```
@foreach(var some in Something1)
{
  @Html.Partial("_Some", new Tuple<Some,MySettings>(some, Model.MySettings));
}
```

Comment: thanks for the tuple idea, not using it but an interesting alternative.